# FloatingActionButton above KeyBoard without "adjustResize"

Tags: android, keyboard, floating-action-button

In my app I am using a `MapView`, an `EditText` and a `FloatingActionButton`(fab), and I want the fab to move above the keyboard when the `EditText` is clicked. I found that setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in the `manifest` works well with the fab, but it also resizes my map which is in background, and it gives a really ugly effect when it's resizing.

Here is my layout :

```
<CoordinatorLayout>

   <MapView/>

   <RelativeLayout>

      <EditText/>

      other views ...

   </RelativeLayout>

   <FloatingActionButton/>

   other views ...

</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any idea on how I could get the "adjustResize" effect without using it ? Or maybe how to exclude a view from resizing but while keeping "adjustResize" ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some researches, I ended up handling the keyBoard by adding a `GlobalLayoutListener` on the root view of my layout, and drawing a rectangle of the current visible part of this root view.
I also added 25dp to the actual height of the keyboard because some devices have a suggestions bar above the keyboard that seems to be included in the visible part of the window.
The `if` condition is there to prevent any translation when a `bottomSheet` is expanded.

```
private void handleKeyBoardApparition() {
    root.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Rect r = new Rect();

            root.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

            int heightDiff = root.getBottom() - r.bottom;

            int suggestionsBarHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,25,getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            if(!bottomSheetIsVisible){
                fabSearch.setTranslationY(-(heightDiff + suggestionsBarHeight));
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this your root view in layout xml,

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

property

Comment: For me the issue only exists because of this line, but I need it for something else...